# Add a permanent Character to UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Is there a way to permanently add a letter to a UITextField where the user cannot delete it? I want to add a single character and the user not be able to delete it but they can still add letters after.

Cheers,

p.s. This is for iOS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `UITextField` has a delegate method called should change characters in range, this method basically ask, should i add or remove the next character? and from that you can dictate what you would like. Here is some example code.

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    BOOL shouldChangeCharacters = ( (textField.text.length + string.length) > 1 ); 
    return shouldChangeCharacters;

}
```

This code means if the new character being added plus the current text is greater than 1 then it is okay to make the change, if the text is not greater than one, then we will not make the change...

Now, under the assumption that someone may try to paste over your character, this delegate method is still called but you have to do a few things.

```
if (range.location == 0) {
    NSString* firstCharacter = [string substringToIndex:1];
    BOOL firstCharacterIsDesiredCharacter = [firstCharacter isEqualToString:@"#"];
    if ( !firstCharacterIsDesiredCharacter ) {
        NSString* symbolWithText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%@",text];

        //  ******************** \\

        [textView setText:symbolWithText];
        return NO;

        // or we could do this

        string = symbolWithText;

        //  ******************** \\

    }

}
```

Both scenarios, are modifying the values of the parameters... some people don't like doing that. It could be a bad programming practice.. or if you are going to modify them there's some process you should do first.

With that, we only need to run this code if they are trying to replace the first character, i substituted the hash tag symbol, the first character is from a range of location 0 and length of 1. So if the range is equal to 0, then we run our code to fix it. This code also takes into consideration that they might be pasting the special symbol with it. so if the `UITextField` read #work, and they tried to copy "work" or "#work" it takes both scenarios into consideration and completely skips the code if the hash mark is the first character.

[UITextField Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField%3ashouldChangeCharactersInRange%3areplacementString%3a)

Comment: This won't work in many cases. For example, if the user selects all text and then pastes in new text or deletes the selected text. This code will allow the change and erase the required character. But this is a start in the right direction.

Comment: when you go to past, is this method not called? if it is, then what you can do is test if string.length > 1 meaning they entered 2 or more characters, if that is true, test to see if the first character is this desired character, if you'd like i can add it to my answer

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
   UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
   label.text = @"left";
   label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.0];
   textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
   textField.leftView = label;
```

Comment: you need to set the frame for label with respect of UITextField

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

in your .h:

```
IBOutlet UITextFeild *textFeild;
```

in your .m:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textFeild {

NSString *textFeildText = textFeild.text;
textFeild.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"string you want to always add %@",textFeildText];

return NO;

}
```

This won't always show up when the user is editing the text box, but once they hit return it will automatically be added to the text box. If you use this code I recommend that you do not have the string that you want in the text field by default, or else you may end up with something like this:

```
String you want to add String you want to add Hello World!
```

If you just use the code I give you and don't put the string that you want to always be in the field by default, you're good to go! If you want to make the keyboard automatically disappear after they tap return just add this in the textFeildShouldReturn method above the 'return NO' statement:

```
[textFeild resignFirstResponder];
```